# Why Next.js does not take into account Accept-Language when rerouting to subdomain?

Tags: next.js, internationalization

Browser get this message:

```
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

I have those i18 settings:

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL', 'hu-hu', 'hu'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
},
```

though `useRouter` returns `hu`. Why?

```js
export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter
```

[image]

Here I tried by setting Chrome language to `nl`, but still `hu` comes in. What caches it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a [`NEXT_LOCALE`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#leveraging-the-next_locale-cookie) cookie set by any chance?

Comment: No, as far as I know, and I do not found any similar value under cookies.

Comment: I had to clean Chrome cache for all the past, not only 1 hour or so.